# How can I label on the dot of scatter plot in this case?

Tags: seaborn, scatter-plot

I just started to learn coding and confuse about the syntax.

I 've the COVID-19 data as below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBLLc.png)

I used seaborn for data visualizing but I 've no idea how to label on each plotted dot with "Country/Region".

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hy7zW.png)

Please advice me as your convenience. Thanks in advance.

P.S. If you 've any idea about data clustering of this data, please share as well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [annotate a plot using matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15148149/annotate-a-plot-using-matplotlib) & [Adding labels in x y scatter plot with seaborn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46027653/adding-labels-in-x-y-scatter-plot-with-seaborn)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Annotate text in facetgrid of sns relplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59774698/annotate-text-in-facetgrid-of-sns-relplot)